# Push Notification Certificates/ Profiles for Watch Kit

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, watchkit, provisioning-profile

I'm about ready to submit my watchkit app to the app store. Finally.

During testing, xcode managed my provisioning profiles for the WatchKit Extension and the WatchKit App. Of course for push notifications I was required to create a certificate for the iphone. Without creating any new AppId's or provisioning profiles for the Watch App/Extension i was able to receive push notifications on my wrist.

The question I now have is whether or not I will be required to create all new apns development certificates for each of the new appids?

Comment: Hi YichenBman can you please help out with the development provisioning profile setup for apple watch targets?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30252953/how-to-set-apple-watch-code-signing-identity-and-provisioning-profile-for-push-n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is No, you don't have to create that for you watch app. When **iPhone** receives notifications, the iOS system will decide which device it should push to. And you do need to create two more app identifiers and two more provisioning profiles in order to let **iTunes Connect** detects that you have **WatchKitExtension**.

Comment: I added watchKit in my existing ios project. I just have to show notification received on iphone from server to iWatch. 
How to do it? could you please guide me. 
I have created provisioning profiles for watchKit and watchKitExtension too. app is installing in iWatch. But i don't know how notifications will go to iWatch.

Answer (score 0):

The Watch simply displays notifications sent to your existing app using the existing cert. You don't need to generate new APNS certs.