# How to set apple watch code signing identity and provisioning profile for push notification?

Tags: apple-watch, ios-provisioning

Got this error:

> Failed to code sign "xxx WatchKit App".
>
> The provisioning profile specified in your build settings
>   (“xxxWatchAppPushProvisionProfile”) has an AppID of
>   “com.yyy.xxxAppleWatchApp” which does not match your bundle identifier
>   “com.yyy.xxxAppleWatchApp.watchkitapp”.
>
> Xcode can attempt to fix this issue.

I've renamed "com.yyy.xxxAppleWatchApp.watchkitapp" to "com.yyy.xxxAppleWatchApp" but it gives this error instead:

[image]

Comment: Solved! Manage to solved it!

Comment: Just got into the office. Let me know if there is anything I can help with

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29272260/1880500